# badge number not updated when application is in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to update the badge number on an app icon. My push notification is coming from the server and I know I will receive it in:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
}
```

My problem is, this method works only when the app is in the foreground but when my application is in the background how can I update the badge number?

I know that the `applicationDidEnterBackground` method will only be called when the home button is clicked.

Comment: and then we have make another api call for reset that number on server  side when application come in foreground.that is not right way.

Answer (score 0):

First of all

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

Is only intended to process notifications when your application is active, it is clearly indicated on the documentation.

The good way to change your badge number using a remoteNotification... is to indicate the badge number value inside the push notification. Please read the manual.